# Can I start using Flutter even though my app is already on Playstore?

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform

I already uploaded my android app (written in Java) on Playstore, and now I want to upload it on  Appstore as well. In order to save time, I decided to use a cross-platform, but I realized that I should have began to develop with Flutter since the beginning.

Is possible to start developing my app on Flutter even though it is already on Playstore? Or do I have to use another cross-platform like Kotlin multiplatform?

Answer (score 1):

yeah sure you can start with flutter, you need to clarify these things :

- package name should be the same as on Play Store.
- you have to choose your old key alias and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

For cross-platform you have to build a new app for the app store
You have java code that does not directly compile in flutter but you can use your logic and architecture which you build earlier you have to build new app for app store

- But make sure you have to use your older package name and key store so you can override your java app(Live on play store) into a flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your app in Flutter and upload it to the Play Store to replace the current one. It’s just a matter of making sure to sign the built applications with the same key as it proves to Play Store that you are in control of both, and you’re making the switch willingly. Also, your new app will have to have a version greater than the one already available in the Play Store, as downgrades are not allowed.